# C# How to make a thread wait for either of two Manual Reset Events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, block

I have a thread that grabs messages from a concurrent queue and writes them to a network stream. The loop inside the thread looks like this:

```
while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    messageBus.outboundPending.WaitOne();
    var message = messageBus.GetFrom(Direction.Outbound);
    if (message == null) { continue; }

    MessageWriter.WriteMessage(networkStream, message, cancel, OnStreamClose).Wait(cancel);
}
```

The requirement is that the thread stops if the cancellation token is set. However, since it waits for pending messages in the queue, the thread will stay blocked. How could I "combine" both the cancellation token and the outbound event so that if either of them are set, the thread unblocks?

The only convoluted way that I can think of to make it work is to replace the outboundPending event with a new third event, and start two new threads: one that waits for the outbound event, and another that waits for the cancel event, and have both of them set the third event when they unblock. But that feels really bad.

Comment: Why are you using a `ManualResetEvent` while a `ConcurrentQueue` dequeue is thread-safe?

Comment: What I don't want is resort to polling the queue since that would consume cycles or make me use Thread.Sleep() which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `WaitHandle.WaitAny` and include the `CancellationToken.WaitHandle`.

A discussion of a cancellable WaitAll can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069467/c-sharp-waithandle-cancelable-waitall)

Comment: Thank you! Seems like what I needed.

Comment: @Hans Note you'll have to dispose `CancellationTokenSource` after accessing `CancellationToken.WaitHandle` which causes the handle to be allocated: *"Accessing this property causes a WaitHandle to be instantiated. It is preferable to only use this property when necessary, and to then dispose the associated CancellationTokenSource instance at the earliest opportunity (disposing the source will dispose of this allocated handle). The handle should not be closed or disposed directly."* [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WaitOne(TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will return `true` if it was signaled, and `false` if the timeout was reached.

e.g, if you send `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` and a second has passed without a signal, the execution will continue and the method will return `false`. If the signal was given, it will return `true`.

Comment: But isn't that the same as polling? The problem is that if the cancellation token is set, the thread will still have to wait at worst the entire timespan to exit. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I'm really hoping you don't work directly with threads, but nevertheless, it can't cause any harm. Consider adding an `if` statement after the `WaitOne` call. If you want to "cancel the operation", you simply don't signal. Why would you care when the worker/thread will exit?

Comment: Another solution would be to use another variable to indicate whether the signal means "stop listening" or "continue execution", and then you could cancel the thread immediately

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. That last idea might be into something, made me think about trying to change it into async / await methods and use a volatile bool to know if to process the queue or not.